# jQuery scroll to anchor returns NaN as location hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Friends,

I'm using following jQuery code which implements the animated scroll to an anchor:

```
(function($){
var jump=function(e)
{
    if (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
    }else{
        var target = location.hash;
    }
    $('html,body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 150
        }, 1500, 'swing', function()
        {
            location.hash = target - 150;
        });
};
$('html, body').hide();
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]:not(#toggle)').on("click", jump);
    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            jump()
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show()
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

As you see from the code above, I use the target offset value of 150px:

```
scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 150
```

In order for this code to work properly, I also need to pass the target with offset to the location.hash. This is how I do that:

```
location.hash = target - 150;
```

Under such implementation, the code works fine. Except it always show #NaN in the URL when I scroll to anchor. This is clearly because of the line above. However, if I don't use the -150px, then it scrolls to target with offset and then suddenly jumps to original anchor location without offset.

My question is, how I can achieve both win win situation? I mean, no #NaN in URL and proper scroll to anchor with offset from top.  I heard that it's possible to use "e.preventdefault", but somehow it doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Well you have a string and subtract a number. Hash has a # sign....

Comment: So why not move the anchor to the offset position?

Comment: I understand that I'm trying to subtract number from string, thats why I get NAN. Unfortunatelly I cant move the anchor to other position, because my page consists of many widgets, which can be reordered. In such case I will loose structure of the page.

Comment: Than you will have to do something different. Maybe you should set the hash and when the page loads you adjust it instead of trying to do something strange. Ohter option is you add the hash with the number and you split it and than so what you do when item is clicked.

Comment: Is there any chance to hide the "#Nan" from the url? I would be happy with this solution, my website is one page layout anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('html,body').animate(
    {
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 150
    }, 1500, 'swing');
location.hash = target;
};
```

I had the same problem and now it works

Answer (score 0):

`location.hash` includes the #, so you if you try to do arithmetic on it it can't be converted to a number.

Use `Number(location.hash.substr(1))` instead.  You'll need to add the # back in whenever you try to use that number as a DOM ID.

(You might consider changing your code to not use the same variable to indicate both DOM nodes and scroll position, though; it's fairly confusing.  If I were refactoring this I'd change those IDs to meaningful labels, and set the scroll position based on those element's `offset().top` instead of on the numeric content of the hash itself.)